# Ошибка Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php

Друзья - выдает что то не то =) Тоесть не те данные что в БД.
Вот код, подскижите что не так, так как если без цикла - то выдет первое значение!
А так ошибка: Warning: Illegal string offset 'product_id' in /home/virtwww/w_ptichshop-ru_5dba0c7b/http/tesst.php on line 12

```
<?php  
        include ('connect.php');   
        $seller_id = $seller['seller_id'];

        $querys222 = "SELECT * FROM oc_ms_order_product_data WHERE (seller_id = 12)";
        $results222 = mysql_query($querys222); 
        $storeser222 = mysql_fetch_array($results222);  


            foreach ($storeser222 as $value222) {
            $ord_id = $value222['product_id'];
            echo $ord_id;
            }




    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не правильно используете [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). Возможно, такой вариант подойдет:

```
while ($storeser222 = mysql_fetch_array($results222)) {
    $ord_id = $storeser222['product_id'];
    echo $ord_id;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но выводит все кроме первого значения

Comment: А вы точно удалили весь код, после строчки `$results222=mysql_query(...)`?

Comment: Да да все ок, спасибо, лишняя строка была, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: никаких проблем )